# How to programmally add nodes with next nid?

Tags: 7, nodes, database

i want to create multiple nodes (from csv file) the csv is loaded well, and my table `node` contains many old records (with `nid` from 1 to 170) what i want is to record the csv's new nodes with nid strating from the last one on table `node` (the new nodes would start from 171 on nid)
I've tried `db_last_insert_id()` with no success.

This is my `db_merge` part :

```
 $nodes = db_merge('node')
        ->key(array('nid' => last_insert_id())) 
        ->fields(array(
            'type' => 'livre',
            'uid' => 1,
            'status' => 1,
            'comment' => 1,
            'promote' => 0,
            'title' => $new_array['titre_csv']<===from csv
        ))
        ->execute();
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`node_save`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7)? Any particular reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way:

```
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->title = $new_array['titre_csv'];
  $node->type = "livre";
  node_object_prepare($node); // Sets some defaults. Invokes hook_prepare() and hook_node_prepare().
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or 'fr' in your case
  $node->uid = $user->uid; 
  $node->status = 1; //(1 or 0): published or not
  $node->promote = 0; //(1 or 0): promoted to front page
  $node->comment = 1; // 0 = comments disabled, 1 = read only, 2 = read/write
  $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving
  node_save($node);
  //save the other table
```

If you want to save it in your custom table you can do a db_insert or EntityFieldQuery.
In that case $node->nid value will be taken after you do the node_save (so do it after you save it with node_save).
You could also use a hook_schema for your table.